# Android File Structure: How do I access stored mp3 files?

Tags: android

I'm making an app for an android phone (Nexus 5). I want my app to access the folder named "Music" that is already there, the same music folder that you drag and drop music files to when connected via usb.

The pathway on my windows 7 computer is:  "Computer\Nexus 5\Internal storage\Music"

It says internal storage in the windows path, but in terms of programming for android is this internal or external storage? This may seem like a stupid question, but from what I read the music folder shouldn't be an app specific folder.

This leads me to ask why I keep getting a null pointer for allFiles when I use this code:

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] allFiles = file.listFiles();
```

or

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File yourDir = new File(path) ;       
File allFiles[] = yourDir.listFiles();
```

or

```
File musicDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
File[] allFiles = musicDirectory.listFiles();
```

Which are just three different ways of doing the exact same thing, except the first two don't go directly to the music folder.

I'm not experienced and new to android's file structure and ect., so if you could answer like you're talking to an idiot, I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The Music folder that you see, is External, in Android terms.

```
File musicDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
File[] allFiles = musicDirectory.listFiles();
```

This should ideally work. You could check what is the absolute path that it returns. Then, see if that folder has any files.

```
String t = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(t);

File f = new File(t);
File[] fs = f.listFiles();
for(int i=0;i<fs.length;i++){
    System.out.println(fs[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```